# when I copy some java code from another online IDE to visual studio code, it shows "unsolved compilation error"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I just copied beneath code from online IDE to VS code.also I have imported java.util.Scanner and other basic things.But when I try to debug that It shows "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:"

```
Scanner num=new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1=num.nextInt();
        int num2=num.nextInt();
        int num3=num.nextInt();
        num.close();
        System.out.print(num1+"\n"+num2+"\n"+num3);
```

---

The full script---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hackerank {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      
        Scanner num=new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1=num.nextInt();
        int num2=num.nextInt();
        int num3=num.nextInt();
        num.close();
        System.out.print(num1+"\n"+num2+"\n"+num3);
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  Please show us the complete stacktrace.  It should include the unresolved compilation error message.

Comment: (The only way I can convince the above to give me a compilation error is if I put it in a file with a filename that doesn't match the classname.)

Comment: Do other programs (simple HelloWorld) compile and run fine?

Comment: Either way, if you get the message cited in the title, have a look at the "problems" tab - there should be a list of errors. If this view is not displayed, you can open it via the menu: view->"Open view"->type "problems" in the search field

Comment: @stephenc you are right the OP filename and class name are not matching this can be the most possible error